# How to install ImageHash on Ubuntu 14.0.4?

Tags: python, hash, installation

I would like to install ImageHash and I did :

```
pip install pillow==2.6.1 imagehash==0.3
```

but I get :

```
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ZDGKpH-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 235, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How should I install it?

Answer (score 2):

The requirements are Pillow, numpy and scipy. so we should follow:

for numpy/scipy:

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran
sudo pip install scipy
```

then:

```
sudo pip install Pillow
sudo pip install imagehash
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed python using conda, try this:

```
 conda install -c scitools imagehash
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run both python 2.7 and 3 run:
 `sudo python3 -m pip install imagehash`